# Java - Assiging content of 3d array to a new 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I have one array where information is stored:

`public static boolean[][][] position = new boolean[][][] { ... };`

And one Array

`private boolean[][] myPosition;`

In the Constructor i wrote

`myPosition = position[pos];`

Whenever I change something in myPosition it changes it also in the position array, which is not OK.

Should i write a new method and use it in the Constructor like

`setPosition(position[pos]);`

which copys the array or what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are assigning a reference pointing to the same array. If you want a copy then yes you are correct, you will need to copy the array.

You should read up on both deep and shallow copies and also look at the Java `clone` feature.